# How to fix DoubleAnimation for rotation of an image?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, animation, storyboard

I am trying to rotate an image on an EventHandler, for an Event that i created. The Event Handler works perfectly fine. Yet the image does not rotate and I do not know what I am missing.

This UserControl is not displayed like this, but in a Grid of another UserControl.

```
    <UserControl x:Class="Mabri.Module.P83.View.SchematicSystemView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Mabri.Module.P83.View"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
        <Image x:Name="drehteller" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>


    </UserControl>
```

This is the code behind the XAML, at first I tried having this in a separat class, if this is possible it would be even better, but at the moment I am just trying to get this running.

```
  {

    private System.Windows.Controls.Image drehteller_image;
    private int currentAngle = 0;
    public SchematicSystemView()
    {
      EventAggregator.SubscribeEvent(this);
      InitializeComponent();
      drehteller_image = new System.Windows.Controls.Image()
      {
        Stretch = Stretch.Uniform,
        Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Mabri.Module.P83;Component/Images/drehteller_unbestueckt.png")),
        RenderTransform = new RotateTransform()
      };
      drehteller.Source = drehteller_image.Source;

    }

    public void OnEventHandler(DrehtellerMoved e)
    {
      EventAggregator.PublishEvent(new LogInfo
      {
        Title = "Should rotate",
        Summary = "The drehteller should rotate now",
        Detail = "The drehteller should rotate " + currentAngle + " is the current angle",
        LogLevel = LogLevel.Information
      });

      int steps = e.steps;
      double timeforonestep = e.speed / e.steps;
      int angle = steps * 72;
      int angle_to_reach = currentAngle + angle;
      Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard();
      storyboard.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeforonestep * steps));
      DoubleAnimation rotateAnimation = new DoubleAnimation()
      {
        From = currentAngle,
        To = currentAngle + angle,
        Duration = storyboard.Duration
      };
      Storyboard.SetTarget(rotateAnimation, drehteller);
      Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(rotateAnimation, new PropertyPath("(UIElement.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)"));
      storyboard.Children.Add(rotateAnimation);
      storyboard.Begin();
      currentAngle = angle_to_reach;
    }
  }
```

In the testing case `e.steps` equals 1 and `e.speed` equals 10.0.

I expected the image to turn for 72 degrees, but for some reasons nothing happens, except for the LogMessage at the beginning of the handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, assign a RotateTransform to the RenderTransform property of the Image. Otherwise it can't be animated.

```
<Image x:Name="drehteller" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
       RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
    <Image.RenderTransform>
        <RotateTransform/>
    </Image.RenderTransform>
</Image>
```

Then instead of setting `From` and `To` just set `By`. And drop the Storyboard and start the animation directly on the control's RenderTransform

```
var animation = new DoubleAnimation
{
    By = angle,
    Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(...)
};

drehteller.RenderTransform.BeginAnimation(RotateTransform.AngleProperty, animation);
```

Finally, do not create the intermediate Image element. That is redundant.

```
drehteller.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("..."));
```

Comment: Do you also have an idea how to do this in MVVM? If yes, please let me know [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57409366/is-it-possible-to-bind-a-c-sharp-storyboard-object-on-an-image-in-XAML)

Comment: What exactly? Animations are view elements. You may perhaps bind the By property to some view model.

Comment: Yes, Binding a Property would be perfectly fine, but I have not figured out what I should bind, I can neither bind a Storyboard nor a DoubleAnimation, plus I would have to Bind the angle and the Duration which seems to cause some problems